# Filter record based on one subform to another

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 3 forms:

frm_Main2
sfrm_ContractDetails (subform)
sfrm_ContractShop (subform)

The subforms are in a tab called NavigationSubform.
From frm_Main2 there is a combobox called cmb_Volume that when selected sfrm_ContractDetails is filtered by VolumeID. This subform has a value called ContractID which I want to use to filter sfrm_ContractShop.

This is what I wrote in the frm_Main2 cmb_Volume after update event:

```
Private Sub cmb_Volume_AfterUpdate()

[Forms]![frm_Main2]![sfrm_ContractDetails].Form.Filter = "[VolumeID] = " & Me.cmb_Volume
[Forms]![frm_Main2]![sfrm_ContractDetails].Form.FilterOn = True

[Forms]![frm_Main2]![sfrm_ContractShop].Form.Filter = "[ContractID] = " & [Forms]![frm_Main2]![sfrm_ContractDetails]!ContractID
[Forms]![frm_Main2]![sfrm_ContractShop].Form.FilterOn = True


End Sub
```

The first filter works well, but the second is resulting in a blank sfrm_ContractShop. What am I doing wrong pls?

Answer (score 0):

You miss the *Form* property:

```
[Forms]![frm_Main2]![sfrm_ContractShop].Form.Filter = "[ContractID] = " & [Forms]![frm_Main2]![sfrm_ContractDetails].Form!ContractID
```